# Is there any typical approach to solving a problem of this kind? (Propositional Calculus)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The image below was retrieved from a past examination on my university database:

[image]

When I asked, my lecturer said he couldn't think of an efficient approach to solve for $\varphi$ rather than through trial and error of arranging the atoms to fit.

*Is there any typical method to solving a problem of this kind?*

**My approach:**

My first recognition: because of the amount of times $\varphi$ is false, it must have many constraints.

A conjunction compound proposition can help satisfy this problem.

The answer I got was $\neg q$ $\wedge$ $(\neg r \vee \neg p)$ $\wedge$ $(r \vee p)$

*This is correct, isn't it? And are there any other methods of solving it, or any other answers that are not mine? I.e. Logically equivalent propositions that appear simpler on paper, excluding all the ones containing double negations*

Here is one I found: $\neg q$ $\wedge$ $(\neg r \wedge p)$ $\vee$ $(\neg p \wedge r)$

**EDIT**: The above (second suggestion for $\varphi$) is wrong due to the arrangement of its parentheses.

It should be: $\neg q$ $\wedge$ ($(\neg r \wedge p)$ $\vee$ $(\neg p \wedge r)$)

Comment: Your solutions are correct, except that the second needs an additional pair of parentheses.  There are systematic ways to derive such a $\varphi$, including K-maps, which are often covered in introductory courses.

Comment: @Bram28 This is basically what I did when I was working it by hand, but you made it more **clear**. Thank you.

Comment: The basis of the completeness theorem for truth tables and propositional logic is that you can turn any truth table into a propositional formula that is provable just when $\varphi(P,Q,R)=1$ when we assume $P,Q$, or $R$ when the corresponding input is $1$ in the table. Typically either conjunctive or disjunctive normal form is used to do this. You should think about how to mechanically (and simply) turn a truth table into a CNF formula. The result is quite verbose but can be simplified. Karnaugh maps are a method that allows producing much more compact formulas from truth tables directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward thing to do is to look at the rows where $\varphi$ is true. So this is in the row where $p$ and $q$ are false, and $r$ is true, and in the row where $p$ is true and $q$ and $r$ are false. So for the first row I can generate the term $\neg p \land \neg q \land r$, and for the second row I get $p \land \neg q \land \neg r$. And now I simply disjunct those:

$(\neg p \land \neg q \land r) \lor (p \land \neg q \land \neg r)$

This can (using Distribution) be simplified to $((\neg p \land r) \lor (p \land \neg r)) \land \neg q$, which is basically the same as the one you got at the end.